# Limiting google contact sync only for upwards sync

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, sync, google-contacts

```
Device: Galaxy grand duos GT-19082
Running OS: CM 13 (Android 6.0.1)
```

**Is there a way that I can disable my contacts `Down Syncing` with google, keeping `Up syncing` enabled?**

Elaborating the problem, I always customize my contacts by adding their contact images (which often gets replaced by their google plus profile pictures as google syncs my phone contacts with google) and removing some extra fields like `Google plus account`, Also I don't like all the email id's(without a name or number) whom I have e-mailed once getting synced to my phone.

But I would like to keep the `uplink` to Google, so that all the contacts are backed up there. I just need to break the `downlink` ("Downsync" which I referred above)